# Export custom fields to csv. React-admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I use react-admin and i need to export not all fields.
In documentations i found how it do. But I have some error.

```
const exporter = records => {
  const docketsForExport = records.map(record => {
    console.log(records);
    const { postForExport } = record;
    postForExport.id_ = record.id;
    return docketsForExport;
  });
  const csv = convertToCSV({
    data: docketsForExport,
    fields: ["id", "filename"]
  });
  downloadCSV(csv, "dockets");
};
```

when i click ExportButton i had a error like this:

```
index.js:2178 uncaught at rootSaga at rootSaga 
 at admin 
 at admin 
 at takeEvery 
 at handleCallback 
 TypeError: Cannot set property 'id_' of undefined
```

Answer (score -1):

O id não ta indo no record, procura em record.data.id ou passa o data ao invés do record

Google Translate Portuguese to English:
The id is not going on the record, searches on record.data.id or passes the date instead of the record.

Comment: Theoretically, const {postForExport} = record;
ja after postForExport.id, then try to give a print in postForExport.id